# In what case std::basic_string::find with a count argument greater than the string length can be useful?

Tags: c++, stdstring

One of the signatures of [`std::basic_string::find` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is:

```
size_type find( const CharT* s, size_type pos, size_type count ) const;
```

The parameters are the following:

> **pos**    -  position at which to start the search
>
> **count** -   length of substring to search for
>
> **s**         -   pointer to a character string to search for

The description of the behavior of the method for this overload is:

> Finds the first substring equal to the range [s, s+count). This range may contain null characters.

I would like to know in what case it can be useful to have a range that contain null characters. For instance:

```
s.find("A", 0, 2);
```

Here, `s` corresponds to a string with a length of 1. Because `count` is 2, the range [s, s+count) contains a null character. What is the point?

Comment: The null character is not special for `basic_string`.

Comment: I believe this flavor of `std::string::find()` is just to use "snippets" out of a longer C string as pattern to search for: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad08bdfb4304fab9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a false premise that you didn't spell out, but combining the title and the question it is:

> The null character indicates the end of a `std::string`.

This is wrong. `std::string`s can contain null characters at any position. One has to be cautious with functions that expect a null-terminated c-string, but `find` is so nice that it explicitly reminds you that it also works in the general case.

C-Strings are null terminated, hence this:

```
std::string x("My\0str0ing\0with\0null\0characters");
std::cout << x.size() << '\n';
```

Prints: `2`, ie only characters before the `\0` are used to constuct the `std::string`.

However, this

```
std::string s("Hello world");
s[5] = '\0';
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

Prints `Helloworld` (because `\0` is not printable). Also `char` arrays can contain `\0` at any postition. Usually this is interpreted as the terminating character of the string. However, as `std::string`s can contain null characters at any position, it is just consistent to provide also an overload that takes pointer to a character array that can contain null characters in the middle. An example for the usage of that overload is (`s` is the string from above)

```
std::string f;
f.push_back('\0');
f.push_back('w');
std::cout << s.find(f.c_str()) << '\n';
std::cout << s.find("") << '\n';
std::cout << s.find(f.c_str(),0,2) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
0
0
5
```

The overload without the `count` parameter assumes a null terminated c-string, hence `s.find(f.c_str())` is the same as `s.find("")`. Only with the overload that has the `count` paramter the substring `\0w` is found at index 5.

Comment: I try to write a little case with a `std::string` containing null characters but without any success: https://godbolt.org/z/dWsTMY The return value of find is always `npos`.

Comment: I'm trying to search `l\0` inside `My\0string\0with\0null\0characters`, right? So, the substring is present in `s`, am I wrong?

Comment: @Pierre the problem in your example is not the `std::stirng` but the string literal, wait a sec, ill add an example

Comment: @Pierre sorry, I messed up the example, it wasnt good and when trying to fix it, it just got worse. I'll come back later to add one